# RabbitMQ what will happen if service that consumed the message will shut down

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I created consumer and producer using MassTransit:

```
var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
        {                
            var host = cfg.Host(messageBrokerUri, h =>
            {
                h.Username(communicationConfiguration.MessageBrokerUsername);
                h.Password(communicationConfiguration.MessageBrokerPassword);
            });
            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, communicationConfiguration.FileResultAggregationServiceAddress, ec =>
            {
                ec.Consumer(serviceCollection.GetRequiredService<IFileResultAggregationConsumer>);
            });              
        });
busControl.Start();
```

My question is: if the consumer consume message1 and in the middle i will shut down the consumer service then rabbitMQ will not get an ack. after 2 minutes the consumer will be alive.

1. What will happen to message1?
2. If the message will gone, how can i use Masstransit to make the message not disappear

Comment: Read more on rabbitmq => https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html

Comment: The message will be in the queue until it is ACKed.